# Wrong predictions when Python writes data into csv

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, sentiment-analysis

I have trained a sentiment analysis model and then I have created a function in Python to predict texts based on this model.

Below is the function to get sentiment (negative, positive, neutral) from a text:

```
def get_sentiment(text):
    
    encoded_review = tokenizer.encode_plus(

          text,

          max_length=MAX_LEN,

          add_special_tokens=True,

          return_token_type_ids=False,

          pad_to_max_length=True,

          return_attention_mask=True,

          return_tensors='pt',

)


    input_ids = encoded_review['input_ids'].to(device)

    attention_mask = encoded_review['attention_mask'].to(device)

    output = model(input_ids, attention_mask)

    _, prediction = torch.max(output, dim=1)
    
    return class_names[prediction]
```

When I tested this get_sentiment function with a single text, it gives correct sentiment:

`get_sentiment('Miksi kukaan ei soittanut minulle??? Olen odottanut kauan!')`

> > negative

Now I have a gigantic csv consisting of texts that I want to predict with this get_sentiment function. I want to input the sentiment next to the texts themselves in a csv. I used the below codes:

```
from csv import writer
from csv import reader

with open('input.csv', 'r') as read_obj,\
    open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_obj:
        csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        
        for row in csv_reader:
            row.append(get_sentiment(row))
            csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

It has appended texts and sentiment in output.csv, but the sentiment now is incorrect:

> > Miksi kukaan ei soittanut minulle??? Olen odottanut kauan!,neutral

Where did I go wrong? Please help.

Thank you beforehand.

--Edit--

Solutions were answered down below. I have tried both and they worked! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thank you to@FloLie and @Daweo! Both of the solutions have worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken your `get_sentiment` function should be feed with text (`str`), but you are doing

```
for row in csv_reader:
    row.append(get_sentiment(row))
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

therefore providing whole row, which is `tuple`. If texts are present in 1st column, then you should grab first column, following way

```
for row in csv_reader:
    row.append(get_sentiment(row[0]))
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as read_obj,\
    open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as write_obj:
        for row in read_obj:
            write_obj.writerow(row + "," + get_sentiment(row))
```

does that work?